# Как преобразовать ссылку Rewriterule?

Tags: .htaccess

Кто-нибудь подскажет, что нужно в .htaccess прописать, чтобы преобразить ссылку вида

```
_http://mydomain.com/aaa/bbb?ccc=ddd
```

в ссылку вида

```
_http://mydomain.com/index.php?p1=aaa&p2=bbb&ccc=ddd
```

Comment: https://web-optimizator.com/chpu-htaccess/

Comment: Спасибо, но как быть с bbb?ccc=ddd ?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался !

```
RewriteRule ^aaa/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+).*?$ /index.php?aaa=$1&bbb=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно  обычное правило с двумя группами захвата, а для того чтобы добавить имеющиеся get параметры есть флаг QSA - query string append.

```
RewriteRule ^aaa/(.*?)/(.*?)/?  index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2  [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Да в роде и так заработало. Но ввсе равно спасибо за ответ !